# How to manage multiple object and struct in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, optimization, struct

I'm currently coding my computer science project.

In short it's like an AOC (Ant colony optimization algoritmh):

Look, I have a two dimensionnal char array which represents the house of ants. And the idea is to spawn food in this array (represented by '*'), and ants (represented by '/' or '\' or '-' or '|' (for the direction of each ant)). I want to have 15 cases with food and to spawn 30 ants.

But here is the problem I have an objet called Ant and one called Food. But how can I handle ? I mean to manage everything I have to code this right ?

```
  Ant ant1;
  Ant ant2;
  .
  .
  .
  Ant ant30;
  Food food1;
  Food food2;
  Food food3;
  .
  .
  Food food15;
```

But I don't think it's the right way. And if I want it dynamic (I let the user choose the number of ants)? I mean, for instance, they didn't write down every PNJ and bots in minecraft right ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're looking for [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), of which the most common is `std::vector`.

Comment: And if the number of objects was fixed, you could use an array.

Comment: Yeah thanks I think it will work. But just one thing : for minecraft or every games with a large number of bots they use containers ?